# What does the sentence " I think an explanation is well overdue." mean?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

> I think an explanation is well overdue.

I've heard this phrase in a movie I've recently seen and I'm not sure what it means. I may have an idea but I'm not entirely sure. It would be of great help if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: What do you think it means?

Comment: What do the words "explanation" and "overdue" mean?

Comment: I don't know what overdue means in this case.

Comment: What do you think the word "overdue" means?  Have you looked it up in a dictionary?  Do you know what an "overdue library book" is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw things between you and Jasper got a little heated in the comment section. I'll do you the favor of answering your question, but keep in mind that not everyone will be willing to help you if you don't help yourself first and do a proper research on word meanings before reaching out to the site.

**When something is overdue it means that it was supposed to be done at a much earlier time and it never got done.** For example if you don't pay your cellphone bill on time it will become overdue and the company that provides you service will shut you off.

Now if **an explanation is overdue** it means that something was supposed to be explained much earlier in time, and it never was. Say you have a girlfriend and your girlfriend gives you signs that she's been seeing someone else without your knowledge, if you confront her and say "I think an explanation is overdue" that means you've been seeing these signs but you never knew why she was acting strange because she never came clean about it, now you want her to give you a full explanation.